# log4j print float as exponential

Tags: java, floating-point, log4j

I just found that log4j prints float as exponential (for example : 2.2388E2) in my application. I want it to display the value as non-exponential. (223.88)

The case happens in customer environment, and I am able to simulate. In what circumstances this thing happen? Any idea how to prevent this?

Extra information : the Envelope Document was generated using CXF, if it does matter.

Below is my Unit Case :

```
@Test      
public  void testSomething()
{

    ServiceEnvelopeDocument serviceEnvelopeDocument  =      ServiceEnvelopeDocument.Factory.newInstance();  
    ServiceEnvelope serviceEnvelope                  =      serviceEnvelopeDocument.addNewServiceEnvelope();
    ServiceBody  serviceBody                         =      serviceEnvelope.addNewServiceBody();
    RsDetail rsDetails                               =      serviceBody.addNewRsDetail();   

    float testFloat = 223.88f;

    AuxiliaryAccountStaticBalanceDetail accountStaticBalance  = rsDetails.addNewAuxiliaryAccountStaticBalanceDetail();

    accountStaticBalance.setAccountBalance(testFloat);

    logger.error(""+accountStaticBalance);
    logger.error(serviceEnvelopeDocument.toString());
    logger.error(String.valueOf(accountStaticBalance));
}`
```

Output for the source code above :

```
2013-01-02 14:55:33.443 ERROR (main) AccountInquiryUtilTest:  - <AccountBalance   xmlns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/account/elements">223.88</AccountBalance>
2013-01-02 14:55:33.465 ERROR (main) AccountInquiryUtilTest:  - <ServiceEnvelope xmlns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/" xmlns:cbs="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/service/CBS-CustAccountInfo-I" xmlns:agg="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/account/aggregates" xmlns:elem="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/account/elements">
  <ServiceBody>
    <cbs:RsDetail>
      <agg:HolderAccountTypeDetail/>
      <agg:AuxiliaryAccountStaticBalanceDetail>
        <elem:AccountBalance>223.88</elem:AccountBalance>
      </agg:AuxiliaryAccountStaticBalanceDetail>
    </cbs:RsDetail>
  </ServiceBody>
</ServiceEnvelope>
2013-01-02 14:55:33.544 ERROR (main) AccountInquiryUtilTest:  - <AccountBalance xmlns="http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/account/elements">223.88</AccountBalance>
```

Output in Customer environment:

```
<ns3:AccountBalance>2.2388E2</ns3:AccountBalance>
```

Comment: Can you share the log4j configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You're logging a string balance, so it can't possibly be log4j's fault:

```
logger.error(String.valueOf(accountStaticBalance))
```

Now String.valueOf() is not very flexible, and you will want to use something else, like [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) (or DecimalFormat). Here is an excerpt from the [official rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29) for Float.toString(), which are the same as for String.valueOf (float):

- If m is greater than or equal to 10^-3 but less than 10^7, then it is represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no leading zeroes, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by one or more decimal digits representing the fractional part of m.
- If m is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10^n <= m < 10^n+1; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10^n so that 1 <= a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

I don't see why these rules would produce different results in different environments, so perhaps you're not showing the right code. These rules don't even depend on the current locale.